# Как сделать select menu?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Пишу своего дискорд бота на python. Недавно узнал о select menu, начал пробовать и столкнулся со следующей проблемой: Меню становится не кликабельным после первого нажатия. Т.е. я прописываю команду, выбираю 1 из 2 вариантов и все работает, а на второй раз пишет "ошибка взаимодействия", что с этим делать?

[image: Вот так это выглядит]

Код:

```
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, ComponentsBot, Button
from dislash import SlashClient, ActionRow, Button
from dislash import SlashClient, SelectMenu, SelectOption
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, ComponentsBot, Button, Select, SelectOption


DiscordComponents(bot)

@bot.command()
async def select(ctx):

    msg = await ctx.send(
        components = [
            Select(
                placeholder = "Выбирете категорию!",
                options = [
                    SelectOption(label = "Модерация", value = 'описание'), #Сделаем краткое описание за место "описание"
                    SelectOption(label = "Резвлечения", value = "Описание")
                ]
            )
        ]
    )
    emb = discord.Embed(title = f'Модерация', description = 'Описание', color = 0xff00)
    interaction = await bot.wait_for("select_option")
    await interaction.send(embed = emb, content = f"{interaction.values[0]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

dislash [больше не поддерживается](https://github.com/EQUENOS/dislash.py#warning) Используйте [disnake](https://github.com/DisnakeDev/disnake) вместо него. Файл с примером select menu:
https://github.com/DisnakeDev/disnake/blob/master/examples/views/select/dropdown.py